# AutoCompleteTextView in android with shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, autocompletetextview

In my application I need to show list of user who are logging in. In my username text field.
I tried to store in sharedpreferences and retrieve but I couldn't. How can I get it done?

I parsed the array to json and stored it in an array then used in a arrayadapter.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

public static String user_id;
EditText etxt_user;
String PLAYLISTS;
String[] listt;

ArrayList<String> array;
JSONArray jArray;

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etxt_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    user_id = etxt_user.getText().toString();

      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        array = new ArrayList<String>();
        jArray = new JSONArray(array);

//          final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(array);
//            editor.putString("buttonArray", jArray.toString());
//          editor.commit();


        final ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();

//  final String name = sharedpreferences.getString("buttonArray", null);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array);
        final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                array.add(etxt_user.getText().toString());

                editor.putString("buttonArray", jArray.toString());
                editor.commit();


                String name = sharedpreferences.getString("buttonArray", null);

                System.out.println("222222222222"+jArray.toString());
                System.out.println("333333333333"+name);
                System.out.println("444444444444"+array);

                editor.putString(PLAYLISTS,etxt_user.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried to store in sharedpreferences and retrieve but I couldn't. How can I get it done? Means what you didn't get String value?

Comment: yes, I need to put string in SP dynamically when user enters and click login button. Then next time when he type his id or name I need to show auto fill option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is static save it in Strings.xml, else you can save it in DB and access it.
Here is the link that will help you http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1342

Comment: No its not static and no DB. I'm trying with sharedpref.

Comment: First of all saving all the users log in the sharefprefrences is a bad idea because traversing and getting all users name to show in edittext would get very hard. Since Sharedprefrences are key value pairs and the name is the key and password is its value in general. but you can use some hacky code for it. 

Okay if you know how to iterate the sharefprefrences and get all the users name then check out this post 
http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext

Comment: In gmail when you start typing your mailid it will show auto fill option with your mail id. So you no need to type your full Id I'm trying the same thing.

Comment: well then its pretty easy .
String name = sharedprefrences.getString("userId");

private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
 name
};
 
// In the onCreate method
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_country);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView is used exactly the same way as an EditText in your layouts (as it’s a subclass of EditText). You just need to replace your EditText by an AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: from where do i get the edit text values. When login button clicked i've to save in SP.

Comment: Editext.gettext().tostring(); 
and save it in your sharedprefrences .

Comment: I did that bro I get single value and I get only the last saved userid. I need to store one or more.

Comment: Thats what I said at first iterating sharedprefrences isnt a good option but you want to do it this way. Anyways you can try this 
start saving as fullname1, fullname2 , fullname3 .... 
when you want to retrieve it 
Arraylist<String> names= new ArrayList<String>;
run a loop 
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
if(sharedprefremce.hasString(fullname+i))
{
names.add(sharedprefrences.getString(fullname+"i"))
}
else
{
break;
}
}

Comment: Glad to be of any help .:)